# How can I configure a scheduled allow list on my router?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, blocking

I want to restrict access to the Internet for myself.
I'm looking for a network wide solution that:

- allows me to block access to the internet for all devices in my local network
- has the option to place addresses on an allow list that is not affected by the block (e.g. stackoverflow).
- has the option to place protocols on an allow list that is not affected by the block (e.g. UDP).
- works on a schedule and does not allow for overrides when it is activated (similar client-side software calls this functionality "nuclear").

I have looked at apps like [StayFocused](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji?hl=en) and [Self Control](https://selfcontrolapp.com/), but these are not network wide, but client-side.

As I have several devices on my network with different OS'es (Linux, Windows) on my network I don't want to configure it on each client.

Comment: Have  you looked around for existing solutions? What did you find? Why did it not work? Please [edit] your question to include your findings so far, such that answerers don't propose something you've tried already.

Comment: yeah but i didn't find any solutions like that. Might be something close is apps like StayFocused, Self Control, but they are not network-wide, only client-based solutions

Comment: Why are client based solutions not feasible? If you're looking for non-client solutions I assume you have some serverlike device available? Perhaps [pihole](https://pi-hole.net/) can be installed on it and configured to block domains? You could also re-write your question to focus on blocking domains with your specific router (after doing some research).

Comment: why client-based not feasible - i have different devices with different OS (linux, windows) in my network. So it might be better to configure it once on a server or router, instead of configuring on each client